# SQL Server Crosstab or table without calculations resultset

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 and I am not sure what I am asking for here but I have a table schema such as this:

```
DECLARE @QuestionRowColDef TABLE
(
    rId int,
    rowcol int,
    rowtext nvarchar(256)
)

INSERT INTO @QuestionRowColDef 
SELECT 1, 1, 'row 1'

INSERT INTO @QuestionRowColDef 
SELECT 2, 1, 'row 2'

INSERT INTO @QuestionRowColDef 
SELECT 3, 1, 'row 3'

INSERT INTO @QuestionRowColDef 
SELECT 4, 1, 'row 4'

INSERT INTO @QuestionRowColDef 
SELECT 5, 1, 'row 5'

INSERT INTO @QuestionRowColDef 
SELECT 6, 2, 'col 1'

INSERT INTO @QuestionRowColDef 
SELECT 7, 2, 'col 2'

INSERT INTO @QuestionRowColDef 
SELECT 8, 2, 'col 3'

INSERT INTO @QuestionRowColDef 
SELECT 9, 2, 'col 4'
```

I would like to return a distinct list of rows and the all columns on for that row. Here's a visual representation.

```
row1, col1, col2, col3, col4

row2, col1, col2, col3, col4

row3, col1, col2, col3, col4

row4, col1, col2, col3, col4
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: So the column values for each row is always the same? I have a feeling that isn't really what you want. I think you need to provide some sample data represents what you actually want.

Comment: In an attempt to keep the result set simple, yes the column values can be the same however ideally the column values would increment by 1 starting at row1, col1. Hope that was clear.

Comment: What do you mean by increment by 1? The values are strings. You need to provide a clear example of what you want here. As it sits right now there just isn't any clarity at all. I assume that the rowcol = 1 means it is a row? I have to say this is one of the worst table structures I have seen in a long time.

Comment: Where is row 5 in your output?

Comment: The omission of Row 5 was an oversight on my part, my bad. I see now that I should not have included the increment by 1 it seems to added to the confusion so the column values can stay the same as initially shown.

Comment: Still not clear. How many columns there can be? Why do you have "col 4" and then "col4" without space? Are those the same values or something else?

Comment: I'm going to hazard a guess that you are doing something like representing a grid (like an Excel spreadsheet) in data, with each cell being a separate row.  Is that close?  And you want to reassemble it into grid format in a query?

Comment: Sorry so late to respond, I got pulled over to another task. Ann L. yes you are correct. The rows would be where rowcol = 1 and columns would be where rowcol = 2. Slava yes the data should have been the same sorry so sloppy in my data representation.